# Is this a valid use case for a "Concern" module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport-concern

I'm working on a rails 3.x app and have some code around logging i'd like to share across M, V, and C.

I'm considering throwing it in `lib` but since this stuff can be used by all and has a specific concern, logging, i thought it might be a candidate for becoming a concern.

Would this be a proper use-case for creating a concern module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. Setting up a logger is not what concerns are for. They're more for adding roles or duck type interfaces made up of multiple methods - that kind of thing.

If a logger is more complex, then you want to put it in an initializer than lib.

About concerns:
http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns